# 11 year old dual Australian British citizen, living in UK and travelling to Australia on UK passport

Tags: passport, dual-citizenship, children, australian-citizens

My British-Aussie daughter lives in UK.  she became a citizen of Australia and has a UK passport.  We are travelling to Australia for a holiday. Do i need to get an Aussie passport for her trip

Comment: Without an Australian passport she'll most likely need an Australian visa on her UK passport, and Australia likely won't issue that visa because she's an Australian citizen.  That's at least how it works in most countries that I'm aware of.  There are some exceptions, though; I don't know whether Australia is among them, which I why I'm posting a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Nobody simply "becomes" a national. Either one is born one or one is naturalised. Please clarify. If she was born a British citizen and holds a full British passport with residency rights, she can holiday in Australia on her British passport plus an electronic visitor visa (free or A$20) readily available online.